# How do I get circulating supply and total supply for cryptocurrencies?

Tags: money-supply, source-code

How can I get circulating supply and total supply for cryptocurrencies?

I am not talking about using coinmarketcap's API, I want to get the data myself. Should I get it from the source-code?

Comment: For all cryptocurrencies/altcoins? That is going to be a lot of work. There are thousands and the vast majority are effectively scams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bitcoin you can get the total supply via [`gettxoutsetinfo`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/blockchain/gettxoutsetinfo/), which produces the following output:

```
$ bitcoin-cli gettxoutsetinfo
{
  "height": 705603,
  "bestblock": "0000000000000000000173b87bcaa99c5020eb16b13a856f7015130889c5ff93",
  "transactions": 45865084,
  "txouts": 75262497,
  "bogosize": 5632719734,
  "hash_serialized_2": "ac0ce667248d97678d5eb4fcfb7e2ae667e205775765852e5b595afa73fb2eb0",
  "disk_size": 4613582238,
  "total_amount": 18847318.79243407
}
```

In the output, `total_amount` refers to the sum of all existing bitcoins. While other cryptocurrencies are not on-topic here, `gettxoutsetinfo` should also work for most Bitcoin-derived altcoins.

Comment: Awesome! And what about other blockchain? any hints?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, this site only covers Bitcoin, but a few other cryptocurrencies have their own stackexchange sites and you could ask there.